# How to optimize my Reduce function in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to create a mapping between keys in a dataframe.

I have a colums R_ID, V1, V2, V3 columns in a pyspark dataframe.
[image]

I need output dataframe that gives me a mapping between these columns. My result should be having like

[image]

I have done this using Reduce but im running into performance issues when testing with large data

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please post your sample as proper text not image. And please show us what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this as follows:

1. collect V columns into array
2. Explode the array
3. Remove rows with null values

The code to implement it is as follows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_ans = (df.select(
             F.explode(F.array("V1_column", 
                               "V2_column", 
                               "V3_column")).alias("v_column"), 
             "R column").dropna())
```

This will result in the following df_ans

```
v_column   R column
V1         RD1
V2         RD1
V3         RD1
V4         RD2
V5         RD2
V6         RD3
```

Comment: thanks @Anna K. , your suggestion worked for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can select each `v` columns separately then union all of them together

**input**

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('r1', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3'),
    ('r2', 'v4', 'v5', None),
    ('r3', None, 'v6', None),
], ['r', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'])

# +---+----+---+----+
# |  r|  c1| c2|  c3|
# +---+----+---+----+
# | r1|  v1| v2|  v3|
# | r2|  v4| v5|null|
# | r3|null| v6|null|
# +---+----+---+----+
```

**select each `v` columns separately

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.select('c1', 'r').where(F.col('c1').isNotNull())
# +---+---+
# | c1|  r|
# +---+---+
# | v1| r1|
# | v4| r2|
# +---+---+

df2 = df.select('c2', 'r').where(F.col('c2').isNotNull())
# +---+---+
# | c2|  r|
# +---+---+
# | v2| r1|
# | v5| r2|
# | v6| r3|
# +---+---+

df3 = df.select('c3', 'r').where(F.col('c3').isNotNull())
# +---+---+
# | c3|  r|
# +---+---+
# | v3| r1|
# +---+---+
```

**Then union them all together**

```py
df1.union(df2).union(df3)

# +---+---+
# | c1|  r|
# +---+---+
# | v1| r1|
# | v4| r2|
# | v2| r1|
# | v5| r2|
# | v6| r3|
# | v3| r1|
# +---+---+
```